# Convert custom object to standard datetime object in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a bit of an odd Series full of Date, Times which I want to convert to DateTime so that I can do some manipulation

```
allSubs['Subscribed']
0        12th December, 08:08
1        11th December, 14:57
2        10th December, 21:40
3         7th December, 21:39
4         5th December, 14:51
5        30th November, 15:36
```

When I call `pd.to_datetime(allSubs['Subscribed'])` on it, I get the error ' Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-12-12 08:08:00'.  I tried to use param `errors='coerce'` but this just returns a series of nat.  I want to convert the series into a pandas datetime object with format YYYY-MM-DD.

I've looked into using `datetime.strptime` but couldn't find an efficient way to run this against a series.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
from dateutil import parser

allSubs['Subscribed'] = allSubs['Subscribed'].apply(parser.parse)
print (allSubs)

           Subscribed
0 2018-12-12 08:08:00
1 2018-12-11 14:57:00
2 2018-12-10 21:40:00
3 2018-12-07 21:39:00
4 2018-12-05 14:51:00
5 2018-11-30 15:36:00
```

Or use `replace` by regex, also is necessary specify year, then use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) by custom `format` - [`http://strftime.org/`](http://strftime.org/):

```
s = allSubs['Subscribed'].str.replace(r'(\d)(st|nd|rd|th)', r'\1 2018')
allSubs['Subscribed'] = pd.to_datetime(s, format='%d %Y %B, %H:%M')
print (allSubs)
           Subscribed
0 2018-12-12 08:08:00
1 2018-12-11 14:57:00
2 2018-12-10 21:40:00
3 2018-12-07 21:39:00
4 2018-12-05 14:51:00
5 2018-11-30 15:36:00
```